# List of devices on which Renderscript doesn't work

Tags: android, processor, renderscript

My app needs Renderscript since it performs some image processing that would take several seconds in Java. Before publishing I have tested it on a number of devices, even some older models (e.g. Samsung Galaxy Tab 2, API 17), and the app worked quite well, even on these devices. From this, I didn't see a reason to set the minimum API higher than 17. Now, some weeks after publishing on Google Play I see that the app crashes on certain devices such as Galaxy S3 (m0) with API 17 or Galaxy S3 Mini Value Edition (goldenvess3g) with API 18.

```
 android.support.v8.renderscript.s: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: unknown failure
```

As such that is not surprising, since I knew about certain processor types that do not support Renderscript or other device specific issues that can cause problems. Questions:

1. Is there a (approximative) way to find out, which of the 6'811 Android devices with API >= 17 do NOT support Renderscript? For example based on the terms in brackets (m0, goldenvess3g) which are possibly related to processor types? If so, I could exclude these devices on Google Play.
2. If there is no such possibility, would you recommend to set minimum API higher, e.g. API 19? Sounds naive, but I didn't find consistent info on this.

Thanks a lot for your feedback.

Comment: If your min API is 17, why are you using RenderScript support library?

Comment: ozbek - this is a very good question! Somehow I always assumed that it was strongly recommended to use the support library, so that I didn't scrutinize the need for it anymore... But it seems that a good part of the non-compatibility issues come from exactly that fact! How ironic. Please put your comment into an anwer and you get the points! Thanks.

Comment: Settembrini - Which BuildTools version were you using when you see this error? There was an issue for RenderScript support lib shipped on certain JellyBean devices, and was fixed Build-Tools 23.0.3.  Also, using native RenderScript on API 17 means you cannot set "renderscriptTargetApi" be higher than 17, otherwise your scripts (.rs) will not work well.

Comment: Phase 1: This specific error I saw with API 17, RS-TargetAPI 18, BuildTools 22.0.1. and support.v8.rs. Later (since I didn't get feedback on the above post)  I changed to minimum API 19, keeping the rest (Phase 2). This still caused me some 1-star reviews because of RS-failure. Phase 3: Now I dropped the support.v8.rs, switched to BuildTools 23.0.3 while still RS-TargetAPI 18 and minimum API 19. Miao - do you think this is fine now?

Comment: Miao- a follow up question for you ;-). Is there a way to filter out devices that are likely not to fully support RS, e.g. based on the term in the brackets as asked in above point 1?  Renderscript is a great thing, but users give you a 1-star rating in a second if it doesn't work...

Comment: Just as a follow up on that. I found that many errors I assumed to be Renderscript problems on certain devices turned out to be other types of problems. It would make life of developers MUCH easier if all users would allow the reporting of crash reports to developers, and I really think that option should be enabled by default, as it doesn't reveal any private information anyway but would greatly help to resolve problems at an early point in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [android.renderscript](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/package-summary.html) documentation, it is available since API level 11. Since your min API level is 17, I would recommend to use it instead of `android.support.v8.renderscript`.

Support library APIs are meant to be used if one is targeting devices running lower versions of Android, which, apparently, is not the case for you.